# Angular 2. What is faster to render: [ngClass] or class="{{}}"?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

What will render faster?

```
  <div class="ololo" [ngClass]="{'my-class': myVar}">one</div>
```

or

```
  <div class="ololo {{myVar ? 'my-class': ''}}">another</div>
```

or some another way?

Comment: I think {{}} renders faster because of digest cycle.

Comment: I'm curious why this matters. My question is not snarky. If there's a use case for this then I want to know what it is.

Comment: @qiAlex Sounds like you're trying to become master of premature optimization ;p. There is no difference.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer. Yes, there is no difference on few elements, but I have a table with few thousands buttons with many classes on each. I'm tracking time from constructor() to ngAfterViewInit() and it looks like {{}} working faster. I feel I will do some test example for this

Comment: The second option will be faster because it will only change className property during change detection cycly while the first option will generate more code for NgClass directive and handle all hooks for this directive(especially ngDoCheck hook)

Comment: Actually I think you are right. Binding to `class` directly is a bad idea in general. This might cause issues here. `[class.my-class]="myVar"` would be the best option in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

I did some research and can surely say that this approach

```
<div class="ololo" [ngClass]="{'my-class': myVar}">one</div>
```

works about **3 times slower** than

```
<div class="ololo {{myVar ? 'my-class': ''}}">another</div>
```

please see a demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fvtzck

Comment: It's 2.5 times faster on my machine.

Comment: can you explain why ngclass is slower ?

Comment: It must be slower, [ngClass] utilizes angular databinding and is dynamic in nature, class is compiled to html and is just running the code with raw js.  The curiosity is more why it is so much slower.