# How to make the list of data move from one array to other using angular8

Tags: javascript, angular

i have 2 set of arrays, one in `Group` and the other List `Not in group`. I have 2 buttons, `move to right and move to left`, so on click of them, the selected data must move to right or to left based on button we select. Here multiple selection of data in list should also be implemented. I have used jQuery but it didnt worked with array of data binded, and the selected list also didnt get `active` in the class, in html, and here multiple list selection is not happening, one at a time is working

Without using jquery how can this be implemented.

DEMO: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzd7q9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

HTML:

```
 <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of agentInView; let i=index" (click)="select(i)" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedIndex == i, 'list-group-item': true}">{{item.value}}</li>
```

Ts:

```
   selectInView(index: number) {
      this.selectedinViewIndex = index;
  }
```

Comment: Just remove the element from one array and push it to another.

Comment: is it possible to remove multiple and multiple at a time?

Comment: You should not mix javascript with jquery, thats a bad practice. If using jQuery, then why using angular.

Comment: I dont want to use jquery, i used javascript itself, i am working on demo, will delete jquery file

Comment: @qiAlex any idea about the question i asked for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a demo with multiple selections and moving from one list to another.

- Selections are getting clear after moving,
- Sort is always by id

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lh5vzl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thats a nice demo :)

Comment: I used to use ngClass always, but from this i learnt without using ngClass also we can add class on condition

Comment: I would better prefer to avoid using ngClass because of it's performance. I have a different topic about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46605252/angular-2-what-is-faster-to-render-ngclass-or-class

Comment: Thanks a lot, really it was informative and it motivates me to learn more, keep up the research work, thanks man :-)

Comment: @qiAlex could you please help me to solve this question , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60360555/how-to-bind-array-of-ojects-to-formgroup-and-formarray-using-angular8

Comment: with your answer, i want that to be worked with reactive forms with same functionality, i have tried upto here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vd8gnv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts